# Reading Trigger and Job Settings from Quartz.Net database through it's API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, triggers, scheduling, quartz.net

I am working on creating a scheduler using Quartz.Net, which resembles Windows scheduler. Something like in image below. I have created UI in MVC resembling the same

I pick these details and make trigger accordingly. Which gets saved in Quartz.Net DB

Now, I have to open these Trigger settings in edit mode. But I can't find a way to read these settings
from configured Quartz.Net database. I don't want to read RAW values directly from DB

Is there any API, from where I can read these values in the same form as I had passed while creating the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all of this information from the Scheduler. The [IScheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/?topic=html/edbcd9ad-0bf8-2b0e-52c9-e8a62ac4f610.htm) interface has these methods that you could use:

```
IList<ITrigger> GetTriggersOfJob(JobKey jobKey);

ITrigger GetTrigger(TriggerKey triggerKey);

TriggerState GetTriggerState(TriggerKey triggerKey);
```